# When I was using the web.js library and Polygon-USDT contract ABI to send transactions, I was prompted that the transfer method does not exist

Tags: erc20

The ABI of the Polygon USDT contract is copied from the USDT contract on the Polygon-scan.

But the ABI does not include the transfer method.

Contracts on blockchains such as Optimism and Arbitrum also do not have a transfer method.

CMD-ERROR:
TypeError: usdtContract.methods.transfer is not a function

How can I solve the problem of the above blockchain sending USDT?